# Viewing downloaded Pdf file in Android version 6.0 not showing up the data

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, android-6.0-marshmallow

My below download pdf file from server and store in sdcard is working correctly in the devices having versions less then 6.0 but in Nexus having version 6.0 the downloaded pdf files is showing some data as three dots.

```
 public static void DownloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory) {
        try {
            fileUrl = fileUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)                                 url.openConnection();
            //urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image: Below marshmallow]
[image: In marshmallow]

Please anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: you are saying pdf is downloaded and not able to view?

Comment: i can view the pdf, the pdf contains table with rows and column ,the table is downloaded but the data inside some cells are coming as three dots(...) and this issue is coming only in marshmallow devices

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and post to let us see?

Comment: And can you share a PDF as downloaded?

Comment: attached the screen shots,  the pdf is opening correctly in the systems but it is viewing as above in the marshmallow devices

Comment: in which app you are viewing the pdf? try other one, its having few issue with drive pdf viewer.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader app, also viewed in other apps same issue

Comment: the issue comes out from the server side, they used different font family for generating the pdf, when changed it showed perfectly in marshmallow also. Thank you everybody for your valuable involvement in my issue.